# Identify and replace duplicate from a column vector

Tags: r, xts

I've got two columns which are as under:

```
a<- c(1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,4,1,1)
date<- Sys.Date()-20:1
data<- xts(a,date)
colnames(data)<- "a"
data
```

Here we can see that there are lot of duplicate elements, ie. they are repeated ones. I want a code which can replace all the elements which are consecutive and duplicate by 0 except for the first element. The result which i require is

```
a<- c(1,0,0,2,3,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,0,1,0)
```

I've tried what i've learnt from my earlier post

```
ifelse(data$a == c(data$a[1]-1,data$a[(1:length(data$a)-1)]) , 0 , data$a)
```

and also i've tried

```
data$a<- replace(data$a, duplicated(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(data$a))))), 0)
```

but both the codes are not working in xts. Though both the above mentioned code is working for normal vector.

Comment: yeah its the same question but that was for a vector and here i need this for an xts.

Comment: So learn how to use data the different data structures. You are asking the same question.

Comment: ok i'll try to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with `diff`, but I think it's simpler than you're making it:

```
a[c(F, diff(a) == 0)] <- 0
a
[1] 1 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0 1 0
```

**Edit**

To make this solution another column, then you can just assign it by:

```
data$b <- ifelse(c(F, diff(data$a)==0), 0, data$a)
```

Or by making a copy:

```
data$b <- data$a
data$b[c(F, diff(data$b) ==0)] <- 0
```

Comment: what if i require this solution as another column in my data saying data$b. ie. i want my a to be same and another column b would give me this solution.

Comment: I've tried the same but im getting Error in error(x, ...) : 
  improper length of one or more arguments to merge.xts

Comment: That's because `xts` objects coerce the first object in `diff` to `NA`. So use `diff(data$b, na.pad=F)` to change that.